# how to pass the current class reference to initialize class members in c++

Tags: c++

My class `A` has an array of objects of class B as members, the requirement is that in the constructor of class A I need to pass `this` to every `B` object in the array. However, trying to loop over them in the constructor body of `A` doesn't work:

```
for (i=0;i<max(B_obj);i++) {
B_obj[i](this);
}
```

---

## code example working

```
struct A : EventHandler {
    A() : B_obj_1(this) {}
    B B_obj_1;

};
```

---

## code example Notworking

```
struct A : EventHandler {
    A() : {
        for (auto i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            B_obj[i](this);
        }
    }
    B B_obj[5];
};
```

Comment: `B_obj[i] = B(this);`?

Comment: Your non-working example is failing because arrays invoke the default constructor for every member of the array.  You can try @UnholySheep's suggestion, or use a `vector`.

Comment: @UnholySheep won't work if `B` has no parameterless constructor.

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks ,atleast this fixed my compilation error. but my program is not working as expected.                                                                           I want to try with Vector that was mentioned by stephen Newell, can you throw some light on it ?

Answer (score 1):

If your only constructor of `B` is `B(A*)` (no parameterless one) then you have to use member list initialization:

```
A() : b_obj{{this}, {this}, {this}, {this}, {this}} {}
```

This gets messy fast though, so a better solution would be using `std::vector` or creating a parameterless constructor and then copy-initializing them later on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , but in my case value 4 is not constant , it always changes, may be my for loop looks like "for(i=0;i<max;i++) {